# Loop through a list of data frames and return names of columns not containing duplicate entries?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, lapply, sapply

Loop through a list of data frames and return the names of columns that contain only unique values, no duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give +1 to BondedDust's answer, as I was also about to write almost same answer... Also as John wanted to have list of such colnames for given list of data.frames, I have added following to lines

```
#dfList is list of dataframes for which operation is needed
myfun = function(df){
          colnames(df)[ sapply(df, function(x) length(x) == length(unique(x)) ) ]}

lapply(dfList, FUN = myfun)
```

I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 2):

```
names(dfrm)[ sapply(dfrm, function(x) length(x) == length(unique(x)) ) ]
```

Comment: Thanks BondedDust. vrajs5 added the last piece I needed to get me up and running.